# calling stored procedure twice returning same result, why?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have stored procedure in mysql as : `sp_get_country_by_id`

```
BEGIN
SELECT id, name FROM countries WHERE id = country_id;
END
```

I am using PDO to call it as follows:

```
$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_get_country_by_id(?)");
$stmt1->bindParam(1, $id);

$id = 102;
$stmt1->execute();
print_r($stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$id = 103;
$stmt1->execute();
print_r($stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

It returns result as follows:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 102
    [name] => Indonesia
)
```

It is expected to return two array as follows :

```
Array ( [id] => 102 [name]=>Indonesia)
Array ( [id] => 103 [name]=>Iran)
```

As per comments, I am adding stored procedure here :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_get_country_by_id`(IN `country_id` INT)
BEGIN
SELECT id, name FROM countries WHERE id = country_id;
END
```

I am following this example. Example explain with INSERT, and I am trying SELECT

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-1028

Comment: Can you add the create procedure statement please.

Comment: @P.Salmon: stored procedure added in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that it returns something with what you have shown. Your `$id` variable probably contained 102 before the `->prepare` instruction

I am assuming that your SP takes the country ID in input, in a variable named `country_id`  which you have not shown

In order to get this to work, you should prepare, bind and execute 2 times:

```
$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_get_country_by_id(?)");
$id = 102;
$stmt1->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt1->execute();
print_r($stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));


$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_get_country_by_id(?)");
$id = 103;
$stmt1->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt1->execute();
print_r($stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

---

But if you have to do this multiple times, its better to create a function for it :

```
print_country_data_array(102);
print_country_data_array(103);


function print_country_data_array($countryID){

    global $dbh;

    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_get_country_by_id(?)");
    $stmt1->bindParam(1, $countryID);
    $stmt1->execute();
    print_r($stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

}
```

Comment: What you suggest is working perfectly, I am using same code before posting the question. But as per the documentation, my code must return what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

A little late here but I faced same issue and the way I solved this is by removing from stored procedure below:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Hope it helps